# MS BOT - How to initiate one to one conversation using AddAggregation method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, bots

Below is the code i am using and when ever i try to connect with it throws error.

```
response =  await connectorClient.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(
                       botParty.ChannelAccount, conversationOwnerParty.ChannelAccount);
```

Error Message : **"This channel does not support this operation"**